# How can I check for an item in a specific slot in Minecraft using JSON

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I'm currently working on an advancement pack for Minecraft and I wanted to be able to check if a player has a certain item in a certain slot of their inventory. This is what I'm working with right now:

```
"criteria": {
        "grab_sand": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:inventory_changed",
            "conditions": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "item": "minecraft:sand",
                        "nbt": "{Inventory:[{Slot:0b}]}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

When trying to put a piece of sand in my first slot it won't give me the advancement. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: What Minecraft are you writing this for?

Comment: Minecraft Java Edition